# Couchbase community edition bucket backup

Tags: couchbase

We are having a 3 nodes Couchbase cluster of the community edition. We are taking the full backup of the cluster using cbbackup CLI tool. It never completed 100% of backup. It stops at a certain percentage of backup and shows the backup is completed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XtgI.png)

Comment: would you please add the complete cbbackup command that you're using?

Comment: Rohit: Can you please provide at least a *little* bit of basic, concrete information about your situation?  We are much more likely to be able to help you if you actual compose a question according to the SO guidelines.